# Problem with VLC's toolbar?

Tags: 16.04, vlc

Whenever I play a movie in VLC in full screen and then comeback to normal view, the toolbar shows up below the title bar 
[image: This is how VLC looks when playing in normal view]
[image: This happen after exiting full screen mode]

How can I solve this??